# Scroll to top of page after ASP.Net Ajax Async-Postback without JQuery

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I need to scroll to the top of the page after an Async Postback in an update panel.  I've tried a couple of methods, and while they all scroll to the top of the page, they all get "overriden" by ASP.Net Ajax which returns the page to where it was when the postback occurs.  I have already set MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="false" in the Page directive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried window.scrollTo(0, 0); ?

If you have, perhaps combine in with setTimeout

```
window.setTimeout("window.scrollTo(0, 0)", 3000);
```

Although I expect this might produce some ugly jumping around.

An alternative would be to hook into the EndRequest event handler

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
function EndRequestHandler(sender, args)
{
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Yes, but as I said, ASP.Net scrolls back down to where the click occurred.

Comment: window.setTimeout("window.scrollTo(0, 0)", 3000);

Comment: Yes, but it is a workaround solution. It smells a bit. Could you try the other idea I had as well?

Comment: Tried this without success. Something is making the page scroll back down to the panel I just activated.