# How to move asp.net page to top in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, webforms, code-behind

If the end user scrolls down a page, I would like to move the page back to the top with a button click. The user clicks the button, and I do validation. The error message is at the top of the page, and the button is at the bottom of the page. If something is invalid, then I want to send the user scroll back to the top of the page so they can see the error message.

How can I do this? I don't want to use java-script, unless I have to. Is there away to do this in C# from the code behind?

I have tried this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), "ScrollPage", "scrollToTop();", true);
```

At run time I get the error: 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'scrollToTop' is undefined

Comment: why you need to scroll to top , if user need to scroll down, this is bad UX or something you might need to explain more to understand your requirement!

Comment: Will the content be different? If not a round trip to the server is not the way to do this and JavaScript/html is

Comment: Why don't you put the validation in a fixed div (`position: fixed`)? That way you don't have to scroll to see it.

Answer (score 4):

You can change code-behind to use following.

`ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), "ScrollPage", "window.scroll(0,0);", true);`

Here `window.scroll(x,y)` means, where to scroll ( x- cord, y - cord ) . I have used 0,0 to scroll to TOP.

You had used `scrollToTop` , to use that you need to have this function in aspx, or use mine.

For more info , refer this - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_scrollto.asp

**Update**

Since OP uses `updatepanel`, I have one suggestion to achieve the same. Use below. I have refereed [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1214763.aspx?Scroll%20to%20top%20after%20update%20panel%20is%20updated).

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
    function EndRequestHandler(sender, args)
    {
       scrollTo(0,0);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: @nate If you are seeing any javascript error , please post that, and how about other browsers?

Comment: I did post the error in my question: At run time I get the error: 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'scrollToTop' is undefined

Comment: @nate , I was asking, if you are using my solution, are you getting error? -- If you clearly examine, **i have not used** `scrollToTop` in my solution.

Comment: There is no error in JavaScript when I use your code

Comment: @nate , So my assumption is, it is working for you. What it means is, if page is rendered fully, there is no scrollbars, then it won't scroll anything, as there is nothing to scroll.

Comment: There is a vertical scroll bar. The page flashes, like it went to the top, but then was reset back to the position of the page where the button is that was clicked.

Comment: Check the below answer, it says `MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback` to be removed or set to false.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67385/discussion-between-nate-and-arindam-nayak).

Answer (score 3):

You can try the following in the page directive

<%@ Page MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="false"

Or in the code behind you can write the following:

Page.MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack = false;

and if you are having async post back than see following post:

[Scroll to top of page after ASP.Net Ajax Async-Postback without JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874981/scroll-to-top-of-page-after-asp-net-ajax-async-postback-without-jquery)

Comment: I have tired this, and I still can't get it to scroll to the top

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need C# for this. You can do this with just HTML:

```
<button type="button" formaction="yoursite.com#top">Click me</button>
```

Comment: I tired this, but it didn't send my page back to the top

Answer (score 1):

Although you didn't want to use JavaScript, you might still consider to use the **OnClientClick=""** property of an Asp.Net element on the view so your business logic can still use the *OnClick=""* property.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" OnClientClick="javascript:scroll(0,0);" OnClick="btnNextPage_Click" class="generic-button" runat="server">
```

This just puts the scrolling back to the very top of the page. 
If you want to have a nice animation going with it you have to include and use a JavaScript library such as jQuery and an relating function.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get any of the above to work for me.

My scenario: I have a GridView embedded in a MultiView.  The user clicks something on the GridView, and it switches Views to output pertaining to what was clicked.  The browser would attempt to stay in the same position on the output as the row that was clicked, which would be part way down the page, or all the way down.

I tried running Javascript to scroll to the top on the click event of the button on the row.  That worked.. but before it switched to the new View, where it promptly scrolled back down.

I eventually tried this, and it works.  I run it after the the View is switched and the content rendered.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType, "scrollKey", "scrollTo(0, 0);", True)
```

I was concerned when I returned to the original View that I'd be at the top of the page of the page again, however the browser scrolls back to the original position on the GridView, which is plain awesome.